# How can I do Python Selenium multiples loops from one element?

Tags: python, selenium, loops, multiprocessing

I want to extract price data from one same element, via 2 consecutive `while` loops functions, by executing first one lazy-loop (like `time.sleep(1)`) that will extract price data every 1 second, and at the same time from second fast-loop (with `time.sleep(0.2)`) that will extract price data every 0.2 seconds.

Code for extracting price data with only one loop that works:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from datetime import datetime
import time

#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~# Cookies Saver:
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=selenium")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)


#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~# Get to the link: 
driver.get('https://coininfoline.com/currencies/ETH/ethereum/')

input('ENTER AFTER PAGE LOADED:')

#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~# Get price data:
while True:
    price_extracor = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@class="cmc-formatted-price"]')
    for price_raw in price_extracor:
        price = price_raw.text

#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~# Time Stamp:
    timestamper = datetime.now()
    timestamper.microsecond

#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~# Date and Price Printer:
    print(timestamper,str(price))
    time.sleep(1)
```

## I expect:

A second while loop that will extract price data AT THE SAME TIME faster with time.sleep(0.2). How can this be done, or is it even possible?

Maybe trying with `multiprocessing` would be possible?

Comment: It will take at least 1 sec to find that element each time so there's no point.

Comment: Have 2 questions. 1) what is the exit criteria for the while loop 2) why can't you get the price each 0.2 seconds and then save value in seconds if the elapsed time does not have the milli seconds?

Comment: @pguardiario Actually with this script, without sleep function, for me running on notebook, takes 0.04 sec to print price data from this element.

Comment: @supputuri 1) There's no criteria for exiting, it just runs infinitely until you just hard stop the execution with ctrl + c.
2) That sleep rule for 1/0.2 sec was just for example purpose, in reality i would use i want to use One loop extracting the price every 0.2 sec, and Second loop extracting without sleep (as fast as possible)

Comment: You should look into MutationObserver instead of polling for changes.

Comment: @pguardiario Do you know some source that will help me understand MutationObserver for use in my question ?